# Confusion between `|` and `&` in Pandas operation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to split the following pandas dataframe into two based on the condition that the (`saleMonth`,`saleYear`) be before (5,2010) or before May, 2010.

df:

[image]

I tried to solve the problem with: `df[(df['saleMonth'] < 5) & (df['saleYear'] < 2010)]` which gave the result (it got rid of 2006 as well for some reason):

[image]

However, when I used `df[(df['saleMonth'] < 5) | (df['saleYear'] < 2010)]`, I got the right result:

[image]

I was not able to figure out why this was happening? Shouldn't the first case say saleMonth < 5 and saleYear < 2010, and hence select the correct dataframe?

Comment: In your 1st case `saleYear<2010` is `True` but `saleMonth < 5` at year 2006 is `False` and you are using bitwise `&`

Comment: Your first function says it must be a year before 2010 and a month before 5.  Your second function says it must be a year before 2010 OR  a month before 5.  Neither of those are what you want.

Comment: You need "year < 2010" or "year == 2010 AND month == 5".  Either that or combine the two into one column (200611) and use one comparison (`datecode < 201005`).

Comment: Thanks @AnuragDabas, that cleared my confusion regrading why the first way didn't work.

Comment: Thanks @TimRoberts, I realised it was luck that the second way worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df[(df['saleMonth'] < 5) & (df['saleYear'] < 2010)]
```

Here you are asking to return all rows that have a saleMonth below 5 AND a saleYear below 2010. So if one of the statements is not true it should not return the row. This should return rows 1 and 2 of your sample data. Row 0 has a salesMonth of 11 which is higher than 5 and row 3 has a salesYear of 2011 which is higher than 2010.

```
df[(df['saleMonth'] < 5) | (df['saleYear'] < 2010)]
```

Here you are asking to return all rows that have a saleMonth below 5 OR a saleYear below 2010. So if one of the statements is true it should return the row. This should return rows 0, 1 and 2 of your sample data. Row 3 has a salesMonth of 5 which is not lower than 5, and a salesYear of 2011 which is not lower than 2010. Because neither of them is true the row is dropped.